# PHP - Nested source of Error-message - PHP.ini

Tags: php, error-handling

How do I get the initiator file of my error? "

I only see the Error Line of the function.php, not the source that called the function.
I need additional: **....index.php on  line 15**"

```
Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/ml/images/raw/test.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/ml/fundtions.php on line 341
```

Comment: Does [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) help?

Comment: same thoughts, but i thought PHP could do the same

Comment: maybe that can be a help : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php